# Decoding JSON to a Map in Scala

Tags: json, scala

I converted a Scala map to JSON using **JSONObject(map.toMap).** How do I decode it to get the map back? Also, is there any better way to enocode Scala Map to JSON and decode it?

Answer (score 1):

`scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject` has an `obj` method that returns a `Map[String, Any]`.

```
scala> val map = Map("zero" -> 0, "one" -> 1, "two" -> 2)
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(zero -> 0, one -> 1, two -> 2)

scala> scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject(map)
res0: scala.util.parsing.json.JSONObject = {"zero" : 0, "one" : 1, "two" : 2}

scala> res0.obj
res1: Map[String,Any] = Map(zero -> 0, one -> 1, two -> 2)
```

Comment: I need to write the above Json object to file and read it back. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the parse method in the [Jerkson](https://github.com/codahale/jerkson) library:

```
import com.codahale.jerkson.Json._
parse[Map[String,Any]](JSONObject(map.toMap).toString)
```